# .NET 4 SpinLock

Tags: .net, f#

The following test code (F#) is not returning the result I'd expect:

```
let safeCount() =
  let n = 1000000
  let counter = ref 0
  let spinlock = ref <| SpinLock(false)
  let run i0 i1 () =
    for i=i0 to i1-1 do
      let locked = ref false
      try
        (!spinlock).Enter locked
        if !locked then
          counter := !counter + 1
      finally
        if !locked then
          (!spinlock).Exit()
  let thread = System.Threading.Thread(run 0 (n/2))
  thread.Start()
  run (n/2) n ()
  thread.Join()
  !counter
```

I'd expect the `SpinLock` to mutually exclude the counter and, therefore, for it to return counts of 1,000,000 but, instead, it returns smaller values as if no mutual exclusion is occurring.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Stephen Swensen has a way to directly access a ref style SpinLock below. `!` returns a copy of structs so should not be used in this case.

You can wrap SpinLock in a class it works (I tried using a static and immutable SpinLock to no avail)

```
type SpinLockClass() =
    let s = System.Threading.SpinLock(false)
    member x.Enter locked = s.Enter(locked)
    member x.Exit() = s.Exit()

let safeCount() =
  let n = 1000000
  let counter = ref 0
  let spinlock = SpinLockClass()
  let run i0 i1 () =
    for i=i0 to i1-1 do
      let locked = ref false
      try
        spinlock.Enter locked
        if !locked then
          counter := !counter + 1
      finally
        if !locked then
          spinlock.Exit()
  let thread = System.Threading.Thread(run 0 (n/2))
  thread.Start()
  run (n/2) n ()
  thread.Join()
  !counter
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like fields in classes are not copied but everything else. If that's right then it also has implications for other applications like complex arithmetic, where you want to avoid copying structs (and C# is currently much faster than F#).

Answer (score 10):

The reason why the SpinLock struct is being copied is because ! is a function: structs are copied when passed as arguments to a function or returned from a function (or any other kind of assignment for that matter).  However, if you access the *contents* of the ref cell directly, no copying takes place.

```
let safeCount() =
  let n = 1000000
  let counter = ref 0
  let spinlock = ref <| SpinLock(false)
  let run i0 i1 () =
    for i=i0 to i1-1 do
      let locked = ref false
      try
        spinlock.contents.Enter locked
        if !locked then
          counter := !counter + 1
      finally
        if !locked then
          spinlock.contents.Exit()
  let thread = System.Threading.Thread(run 0 (n/2))
  thread.Start()
  run (n/2) n ()
  thread.Join()
  !counter
```

Answer (score 8):

SpinLock is a value type. When you dereference your spinLock variable (!spinLock), the struct got copied, and the lock you enter/exit is now different.