# Initializing an infinite list of BigIntegers

Tags: f#, ienumerable, sequence, biginteger, seq

Ok,
So I need a list of all the positive integers.
What first comes to mind is:

```
let numbers:Seq<bigint>=Seq.initInfinite n...
```

but initInfite isn't actually infitint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx
(unlike bigint) its only: Int32.MaxValue = 2,147,483,647 which is nowhere near big enough.

Currently my plan is to replace the sequence with some kind of handmade class (possibly implimenting IEnumerable). It would be simple (and possibly more effiecint for my use) but i want to know how to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let numbers:bigint seq = 
    let rec loop n = seq { yield n; yield! loop (n+1I) }
    loop 0I
```

Comment: Yes.. I wish F# had type classes (as in Haskell) so that we didn't need the "skip" parameter in generic solution

Comment: @Joel - just in case future readers don't read the full comment thread under Daniel's answer, I want to reiterate that there is no boxing in my version, just a single *generic* ref cell on the heap which is updated with each iteration.

Comment: I also updated my answer with an example of how to use generic language primitives to easily write a version of my function in terms of the original more flexible version with skip 1 built-in.

Answer (score 12):

```
Seq.unfold (fun n -> Some(n, n + 1I)) 0I
```

Comment: Does the I suffix indicate a literal is a bigint?

Comment: Except 0 isn't a positive integer (everyone else made the same error).

Comment: @Stephen: I suspect everyone made their function symmetric with `Seq.initInfinite`, which starts with 0. It seems more useful to do so. You can always `Seq.skip 1` if needed.

Comment: @Brian What?  You're not running mono on your phone yet? :)

Answer (score 3):

I keep the following statically constrained function around since it is very flexible (you can specify the start value and the skip interval) and works with all numeric types:

```
let inline infiniteRange start skip = 
    seq {
        let n = ref start
        while true do
            yield n.contents
            n.contents <- n.contents + skip
    }
```

Type signature given by FSI:

```
val inline infiniteRange :
   ^a ->  ^b -> seq< ^a>
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a)
```

Here is how you generate all *positive* integers (BigInts, that is -- shown in FSI):

```
> infiniteRange 1I 1I;;
val it : seq<System.Numerics.BigInteger> =
  seq [1 {IsEven = false;
          IsOne = true;
          IsPowerOfTwo = true;
          IsZero = false;
          Sign = 1;}; 2 {IsEven = true;
                         IsOne = false;
                         IsPowerOfTwo = true;
                         IsZero = false;
                         Sign = 1;}; 3 {IsEven = false;
                                        IsOne = false;
                                        IsPowerOfTwo = false;
                                        IsZero = false;
                                        Sign = 1;}; 4 {IsEven = true;
                                                       IsOne = false;
                                                       IsPowerOfTwo = true;
                                                       IsZero = false;
                                                       Sign = 1;}; ...]
```

**Update:** and as Daniel showed, you can use generic language primitives to easily write another statically constrained function in terms `infiniteRange` with skip 1 built-in:

```
let inline infiniteRangeSkip1 start = 
    infiniteRange start LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
```

Here's the type signature:

```
val inline infiniteRangeSkip1 :
   ^a -> seq< ^a>
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a) and
          ^b : (static member get_One : ->  ^b)
```

Comment: Is there a particular advantage here to accessing `n.contents` directly instead of using the (idiomatic) `!` and `:=` operators?

Comment: @ildjarn - in this case I don't think there is any advantage (see @Daniels benchmarks). in general I simply don't like the look of those operators and am content to think of ref cells as normal objects (but perhaps I should get in line). but I've also been a bit wary of the ref cells operators ever since answering a question where they introduced different behavior from accessing `contents` directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019446/net-4-spinlock/3027205#3027205

Comment: @Stephen : Interesting, thanks. I completely assumed that said operators were defined as `inline`; I don't suppose you know the rationale behind them _not_ being `inline`?

Comment: @ildjarn - I don't except I think the F# designers tried to avoid `inline` (for fear of bloat) except where they saw it as essential, so I think they just overlooked this scenario. Another case is `raise`, which I believe absolutely should be inlined so it doesn't dirty stack traces yet isn't.

Comment: @Stephen : I would consider it a bug rather than an oversight in this case since it changes (and sometimes breaks, as you noted) the semantics of `ref`. And I suppose it's too late to change the semantics of something so fundamental as a built-in operator now. :-[

Comment: Hrm, actually, looking at the generated IL of Daniel's `initInfiniteBig` and `initInfiniteBig2` state machines, they're byte-for-byte identical -- I now suspect operators `!` and `:=` were made `inline` in SP1 (I was looking at the pre-SP1 compiler source earlier when I saw they weren't).

Comment: @ildjarn - interesting, I also saw they were not `inline` in the pre-SP1 source code (I don't even have SP1 installed since I heard it was buggy -- I wonder if there are any release notes available for changes like that...).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I bet Brian would tell us whether or not this particular change was made if we ask him nicely. ;-] Also, regarding SP1 being buggy -- it's not; there is a manifest file that doesn't get properly updated if you had previously installed the SP1 beta, but that's a trivial fix, and if you _hadn't_ previously installed the SP1 beta there's no issue at all.

Answer (score 2):

You might even consider extending the `Seq` module if this is something you frequently need.

```
module Seq =
  let initInfiniteBig = 
    seq {
      let i = ref 0I
      while true do 
        yield !i
        i := !i + 1I
    }

let ten = Seq.initInfiniteBig |> Seq.take 10
```

### Update

I benchmarked a few variations:

```
let initInfiniteBig = 
  seq {
    let i = ref 0I
    while true do 
      yield !i
      i := !i + 1I
  }

let initInfiniteBig2 = 
  seq {
    let i = ref 0I
    while true do 
      yield i.contents
      i.contents <- i.contents + 1I
  }

let initInfiniteBig3 = 
  let rec loop i = 
    seq {
      yield i
      yield! loop (i + 1I)
    }
  loop 0I

let initInfiniteBig4 = Seq.unfold (fun n -> Some(n, n + 1I)) 0I

let range s = s |> Seq.take 100000000 |> Seq.length |> ignore

range initInfiniteBig  //Real: 00:00:29.913, CPU: 00:00:29.905, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
range initInfiniteBig2 //Real: 00:00:30.045, CPU: 00:00:30.045, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
range initInfiniteBig3 //Real: 00:00:40.345, CPU: 00:00:40.310, GC gen0: 2289, gen1: 5, gen2: 0
range initInfiniteBig4 //Real: 00:00:30.731, CPU: 00:00:30.716, GC gen0: 1146, gen1: 4, gen2: 1
```

### Update 2

Here's a generic range function, like Stephen's, but without `start` and `skip`.

```
let inline infiniteRange() : seq<'a> = 
  let zero : 'a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  let one : 'a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  seq {
      let n = ref zero
      while true do
          yield !n
          n := !n + one
  }
```

Here's the signature:

```
unit -> seq< ^a>
    when  ^a : (static member get_Zero : ->  ^a) and
          ^a : (static member get_One : ->  ^a) and
          ^a : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^a)
```

And the benchmark:

```
range (infiniteRange() : seq<bigint>) //Real: 00:00:30.042, CPU: 00:00:29.952, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Comment: I would **strongly** favor recursion here rather than use of `ref`, since this unnecessarily boxes every element (`bigint` is a value type).

Comment: @Daniel, @ildjarn -- indeed, I did similar benchmarks a while back and also found ref cell in a `while true` loop was the best.

Comment: @ildjarn: You would think, but it turns out not to be the case. In fact, the recursive version is the only one that's discernibly slower. I updated my answer with benchmarks.

Comment: @Stephen: There also seems to be no benefit to accessing `contents` directly.

Comment: @Daniel : Very interesting, and unexpected.

Comment: @ildjarn - why should there be any boxing involved here? ref is a generic type.

Comment: @Stephen : Apparently I'm not awake enough yet. My line of thought was that because `ref` itself is a reference type, each use of `ref` would effectively box the value it contains -- in and of itself, accurate. But of course, in this code there is only a single use of `ref`, as opposed to one use of `ref` per element. I think I'll stop commenting for a few hours until my brain is doing its job better. :-P

Comment: @Daniel - Your version without `start` and `skip` parameters is going to default to `int` unless you specify otherwise when you call it. I think that's the main reason it's faster than the other ones, which are all hard-coded to `BigInt`. I found it to be slightly slower than an `int` version of `infiniteBig`.

Comment: @Joel: Good catch. I forced it to `bigint` and it now seems comparable to the others. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Daniel, @Stephen : I looked at the generated IL for the recursive version, and the code generated for its state machine is abysmal (possibly a pathological case, but I doubt it). By my count, when the first element is yielded there is 1 reference allocation and 7 `bigint` value copies; elements subsequently yielded each cause 2 reference allocations and 12 `bigint` value copies, 1 and 5 of which (respectively) are completely unused/wasted. I haven't looked at the output of the C# compiler for a roughly-equivalent C# enumerator, but I imagine it must be significantly better than this... :-/

Comment: @ildjarn: That definitely explains the amount of GC's.

Comment: @ildjarn: [Here](http://pastebin.com/AsfuLHvY) is a C# version, along with decompilation, if you want to see how it compares.

Comment: @Daniel : That looks more like a corollary to your `initInfiniteBig(2)`, not your `initInfiniteBig3` (I didn't check to see what F#'s `ref`-based state machines looked like since they were winning performance-wise). That said, I realize that the C# compiler doesn't emit tail-calls, so it may not be possible to create an equivalent recursive C# version at all.